# Specifying arbitrary compiler arguments in a Visual Studio project file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

When using Visual Studio to compile a C++ project, you can set various properties (for optimisation, code generation, linking et cetera) that msbuild translates into appropriate commandline options to cl.exe.

Suppose you want to specify some extra options that msbuild doesn't know about. Is there a way to specify arbitrary compiler arguments in a .vcxproj file, as in 'here is a string, don't worry about what it means, just pass it on to the compiler'?

Comment: Even the IDE allows you to do so, so I'm wondering why you didn't find it in project properties.

Comment: In VS: Project Properties->C/C++->Command Line. In the project file: `AdditionalOptions` under the `ClCompile` item group. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1a0ad47.aspx for general description btw, which describes pretty much exactly what you are asking.